# How to change text color if one var is greater than or equal to another var?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a small script to change the color of some span text based on the value of available characters left when typing in a text box.

I have the counter working which shows the number of characters left, but I can't seem to get the color to change when the number of characters left is greater than or equal to the number of max characters allowed.

Here's my javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var maxChar = 300;

  $("textarea").keyup(function() {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    var charCount = maxChar - length;
    $("#charCount").text(charCount);
    if (charCount >= maxChar) {
      document.getElementById("charCount").style.color = "#ff3343";
    }
  })

});
```

HTML for text box:

```
<div class="form-group col-12">
  <label for="hostDesc">Description</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="hostDesc" id="hostDesc" min="0" maxlength="300" data-ng-model="hostDesc" aria-describedby="descHelp" placeholder="Leave a description" rows="8" style="height: 150px" required></textarea>

     <p class="text-small text-muted mb-0"><span id="charCount">300</span> characters remaining</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Think about what you are doing.  Your `charCount` is your `maxChar - length`. As you type, your charCount gets smaller and smaller....

Comment: @Taplar Facepalm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You had the `>=` the wrong way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxChar = 300;
  $("textarea").keyup(function() {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    var charCount = maxChar - length;
    $("#charCount").text(charCount);
    if (charCount <= maxChar) {
      document.getElementById("charCount").style.color = "#ff3343";
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-12">
  <label for="hostDesc">Description</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="hostDesc" id="hostDesc" min="0" maxlength="300" data-ng-model="hostDesc" aria-describedby="descHelp" placeholder="Leave a description" rows="8" style="height: 150px" required></textarea>

  <p class="text-small text-muted mb-0"><span id="charCount">300</span> characters remaining</p>

</div>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I ended up switching "charCount" with "length" and it works with the same operator.